# Detect an incompatible API change without version change

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, compatibility, semantic-versioning

I'm using semantic versioning on a `Java - Maven - Jenkins` project and accordingly, whenever an incompatible API change is done, the major version of the product should be changed. 
I'm looking for an automated way to detect such a change, so that the maven build would fail if it happened (or even automatically increase the version). Googling has me on the track of writing my own `maven enforcer plugin` rule, but I want to ask if anybody knows about any tool that can help (`Jenkins` plugin or similar  would also work).

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at [animal-sniffer-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/) ?

Comment: I did already but it doesn't do what I want. It checks that your code compiles against older/newer dependency APIs

Comment: There is also the clirr plugin: http://mojo.codehaus.org/clirr-maven-plugin/ that does a similar thing.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was looking for, thanks! Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A year has passed but I hope this can help someone in the future.
Based on the comment by [wemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048093/wemu), I found this:

**Clirr**

- Command Line: http://clirr.sourceforge.net/
- Maven Plugin: http://www.mojohaus.org/clirr-maven-plugin/
- SonarQube Plugin: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Clirr+Plugin

**Java API Compliance Checker**

- Command Line: https://github.com/lvc/japi-compliance-checker

**Revapi** (Supports Java 8)

- Home: http://revapi.org
- Maven Plugin: https://github.com/revapi/revapi
- Aditional Info: http://massol.myxwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Blog/ByeByeCLIRRWelcomeRevapi

**japicmp** (Supports Java 8)

- Command Line / Maven Plugin: http://siom79.github.io/japicmp/

Comment: Revapi seems to be the better choice of these.