# Unit test to catch the situation where if we rename or delete an attribute in a Java/Spring Boot data model

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, unit-testing, integration-testing

I have to catch the situation whenever any attribute name is renamed or deleted from a java/spring boot data model. My project uses java, spring boot and hibernate.

**How can I know when an attribute is renamed/deleted ?**

Any hint/idea will be very helpful.

Comment: You may want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455078).

Comment: do you mean the entities changes which are mapped to database tables / columns? Stuff like column renaming?

Comment: @MarkBramnik Yes, the column renaming.

Comment: @MarkBramnik any approach regarding how to check the column renaming/deletion using code/unit test/integration test ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'check'? If someone renames a column without also preparing an appropriate DB migration to adjust the DB tables, then the integration tests will fail, thus 'checking' the change (you are, of course, using DB migrations for managing the schema, right?)

Comment: @crizzis Yes, using flyway db tool for db migration using sql scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me express some general thoughts:

It basically depends on what is your baseline, when you change the column, where do you maintain such a change and how does the change made in code propagates to the actual database.
Since usually the code is "static" and represents the state of the project in time, you might need an external database with the previous version of the code deployed to compare to. This in general complicates the  tests because tests usually need to check a functionality of the current version of code and not to compare it with the previous versions or something.

So I would consider implementing such a check not as a test but as an external verification tool that can run during the build (say in CI).
Also what happens if this tool fails? Like ok, someone has indeed changed the column, so what? Should the whole build fail? If so how will the project evolve? After all the db changes happen and probably for good reasons...

So, assuming you still want to implement such a tool, read on:

One approach is to maintain migrations, tools like Flyway and Liquibase come to the rescue here.

The idea is that each change will be documented in code by means of a special "migration" script / file.
For example in Flyway there is a special table in db that contains the state of applied migrations so you can query it in the test and see whether you have more recent migrations to apply for example (each migration will change the db schema)

Another approach is using hibernate mappings in the entity annotations for example.
In this case You can try to check whether the current mapping can be applied to the current database state (its called mappings validation): Technically there is a property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` that can be set to `validate` (read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116625/how-to-validate-hibernate-mapping-against-database) for more details)

The last possible option concept that comes to my mind:
Compare the metadata of 2 schemas: One baseline (prepared in advance - this is the one you verify your mappings against) - query its metadata (tables, column names, indices, constraints, whatever you need)
Then create a "sample schema" our of your hibernate mappings (you might want to use testcontainers for the db, if its possible) or even the real database to create a "mock" schema.
Now Query the metadata of this new schema and compare with the first "baseline" schema. Probably it will use some custom solutions because you'll end up with some custom checks sooner or later (this change is ok, but that change is not) I believe..

Comment: Thanks ! Yes, this is the exactly what I needed. I am using flyway db as data migration tool and got the way how to check if columns are changed or not. I am just checking the migration sql scripts and checking if it contains the column name updation condition.